# What's the word for a party to whom a business proposal is made?

Tags: single-word-requests

What's a single word for a party who is made a business proposal to, i.e. the person or persons to whom a proposal is submitted?

Comment: The *mark.* ;-)

Comment: That's "the party of the first part."  They should be referred to as the party of the first part.  ;-)

Comment: Thank you. That's something new I just learnt. A legal phrase, perhaps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Suitor and solicited**.
The one who makes the proposal may be termed the Suitor:

- Business suitor
- Financial suitor
- Investment suitor

The verbs of the action of the suitor either preceding or following the proposal could be termed *court*, *woo*, *solicit*.

Therefore, we could use the term *solicited party*, e.g. *solicited company*.

> Acting on the merger proposal, both the suitor and solicited corporations have met to draw the list of possible positions which would be declared redundant.

**Proposer and proposed-party**.

> Both the proposing and proposed companies of the joint-marketing campaign celebrated their deal with much fanfare and publicity.

**Offeror and offeree** - in the case where the proposal was made as an offer or to obtain an offer.

> The young entrepreneurs (offeree, proposer) made a proposal to the investment bank (solicited offeror), who would offer them a some funds.
>
> The investment bank (offeror, proposer) made a proposal to the start-up company (solicited offeree) offering to invest in that company.