# single word noun for the author of a grant proposal

Tags: single-word-requests

I was wondering if there is a shorter way (preferably a single word noun) to refer to the author of a grant proposal?

I looked up the word "proposer", but can't find the exact same usage in any dictionaries. Google search suggests that this is a French word.

The closest thing I can find is an example in this ESL question: [What's the word for a party to whom a business proposal is made?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/123527/85110)

> **Proposer and proposed-party.**
>
> Both the proposing and proposed companies of the joint-marketing
>   campaign celebrated their deal with much fanfare and publicity.

But the example cites no sources and doesn't actually contain the word "proposer". In addition, I'm not sure if it's the same context as a grant proposal.

Could anyone offer an official source, or suggest an alternative?

Comment: If you are writing a grant you are usually considered an applicant.

Comment: If you win a grant, you are a recipient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would call the author of a grant the ***Grant Writer***.  The US Department of Labor's Bureau of Labor Statistics [describes the job of a grant writer](https://www.bls.gov/careeroutlook/2014/youre-a-what/grant-writer.htm) thusly:

> Grant writers research, draft, and submit proposals that help organizations or individuals receive grant funding.

I hope this helps.

Comment: the writers' help' the recipients of grants ie the grantee.